# Query to sum subsequent durations that do not run concurrently

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that pulls the start and end times of delays for an event, and calculates the length in a CTE. There can be several delays associated with a single event, but because of user error delays can happen concurrently. I want to write a query that sums all consecutive delays together, including a single duration for any that run concurrently as calculated by the delay that started earliest.

To get a data table:
        USE [tempdb]

```
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDelay](
        [Delay_ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
        [EventID] [INT] NOT NULL,
        [D_Time] [Datetime] NOT NULL,
        [D_EndTime] [Datetime]
        )
GO

INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(1,1,'10:00','10:01');
INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(2,1,'10:05','10:06');
INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(3,1,'10:05:01','10:06');
INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(4,2,'10:00','10:01');
INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(5,2,'10:04','10:05');
INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(6,2,'10:06','10:07');
INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(7,2,'10:06:01','10:07');
INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(8,2,'10:10','10:12');
INSERT INTO tblDelay VALUES(8,2,'10:10:01','10:12');
```

I've attempted to do this by using LEFT self-JOIN to select for the immediate next delay, then sum up the results. I can do multiple self-joins, but I want it to scale automatically, not just to test for a set number of delays. Code below works:

```
WITH DelLength AS
(
    SELECT 
        EventID, Delay_ID,
        D_time, d_EndTime,
        CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, D_Time, D_EndTime) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / 60 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS DelLength
    FROM 
        tblDelay d
)
SELECT
    dl1.EventID,
    dl1.D_Time,
    dl1.D_EndTime,
    (dl1.DelLength + dl2.DelLength + dl4.DelLength) AS Total
FROM
    DelLength AS dl1
INNER JOIN 
    tblEvent e ON dl1.EventID = e.EventID
LEFT JOIN 
    DelLength AS dl2 ON dl1.EventID = dl2.EventID
                     AND dl2.D_Time = (SELECT TOP 1 dl3.D_Time
                                       FROM DelLength dl3
                                       WHERE dl3.EventID = dl1.EventID
                                         AND dl3.D_Time > dl1.D_EndTime
                                       ORDER BY dl3.D_Time)
LEFT JOIN 
    DelLength dl4 ON dl4.EventID = dl1.EventID
                  AND dl4.D_Time = (SELECT TOP 1 dl5.D_Time
                                    FROM DelLength as dl5
                                    WHERE dl5.EventID = dl1.EventID
                                      AND dl5.D_Time > dl2.D_EndTime
                                    ORDER BY dl5.D_Time)
```

Produces a record for each event and sum of first, second and third subsequent delay as described (if present). But I want to code for and indefinite number of subsequent delays.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a solution to virtualize islands groups within an ordered sequence by time. Something similar to the query below may help. Virtualize a grouping and take the min and max per group, individual records or non-island records will be ordered sequentially as they fall while all records within an island will have the same sequential order as the first record in the group.

```
;WITH Markers AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        VirtualGroupID = SUM(IsNewGroup) OVER (ORDER BY D_Time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM
    (        
        SELECT
            EventID, Delay_ID,
            D_time, d_EndTime,
            IsNewGroup = CASE WHEN ISNULL(LAG(EventID) OVER (ORDER BY D_Time),EventID)<>EventID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM
            tblDelay d
    )AS X
)

SELECT 
    EventID = MAX(EventId),
    d_Time = MIN(d_Time),
    d_EndTime = MAX(d_EndTime)
FROM 
    Markers
GROUP BY
    VirtualGroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for putting me on the right track Ross. I found that your answer was 90% of the way to what I was looking for, simply needed to be supplemented with an elaboration on the window expression in the inner-most subquery. To prevent pulling in of delays that started before the last one ended I expanded the code:

```
WITH Markers AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        VirtualGroupID = SUM(IsNewGroup) OVER (ORDER BY D_Time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM
    (        
        SELECT
            EventID, Delay_ID,
            D_time, d_EndTime,
            IsNewGroup = CASE 
                        WHEN        
ISNULL(LAG(EventID) OVER (ORDER BY EventID, D_Time),EventID)<>EventID 
                        OR          
(LAG(EventID) OVER (ORDER BY EventID, D_Time) = EventID 
AND D_Time > LAG(D_EndTime) OVER (ORDER BY EventID,D_Time)) 
                        THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 END
        FROM
            tblDelay d
    )AS X

)

SELECT 
    EventID = MAX(EventId),
    d_Time = MIN(d_Time),
    d_EndTime = MAX(d_EndTime)
FROM 
    Markers

GROUP BY
    VirtualGroupID
    ORDER BY EventID
```

I think that gets it right.

Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear that you have the correct results now and glad I could be of assistance.